# Get user avatar and send it in channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
yummy.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(message.content === 'wtfava') {
        message.channel.send(message.author.avatarURL)
    }
});
```

How can I get the avatar URL from user when he types the command `wtfava`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `displayAvatarURL`. If you want to display gifs too, you can add the `{dynamic: true}` option. This way the format will dynamically change to gif for animated avatars:

```js
yummy.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(message.content === 'wtfava') {
        message.channel.send(
            message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: but what if avatar .gif?

Comment: yes and it gives you just a pic instead of gif

Comment: You can add `{dynamic: true}`. I've just updated my answer.