# displayAvatarURL() returns an .webp image instead of a .gif

Tags: discord.js

my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('avatar')
        .setDescription('Get the avatar URL of the selected user.')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('The user\'s avatar to show')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

        embed.setTitle(`${user.username}'s avatar`);
        embed.setURL(user.avatarURL);
        embed.setColor('RANDOM');
        embed.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL() + "?size=1024");

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
};
```

basically i want it to display the original image/gif instead of the .webp file because for some reason it displays a .webp file

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127359/get-user-avatar-and-send-it-in-channel/66127387#66127387

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.displayAvatarURL()` takes https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions that includes a `dynamic` option:

> "If true, the format will dynamically change to `gif` for animated avatars."

```js
user.displayAvatarURL({
   dynamic: true 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll verify if it works tomorrow since from what I remember it gives some error